# Using a array formula instead of a per row formula

Tags: google-sheets

I am new to Array Formulas but they seem great. I have a working implementation of what I want with a function "per row" but it fragile to new rows being added (where the formula will not be included).

For context, I have a sheet which looks like:

[image]

The idea is that there are several columns which represent "scope" but the multiple columns represent a means to created a nested list. However, I want to always know which high-level category we are in (aka, "Design" and "Implementation").

I currently have the following formula on each row:

```
 =IFERROR(
    INDEX(
      FILTER($D$6:$D,$D$6:$D <> ""),
      INDEX(QUERY($D$6:D6,"select count(D) where D <> ''"),2,1)
    )
    ,""
 )
```

Where `D6` is moved to `D7`, etc. as we move down each row.

Sadly, I have been trying to figure out an Array formula -- which I can set on the top row only -- but just can't seem to get there. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: As you state, "there are several columns which represent "scope" but the multiple columns represent a means to created a nested list", does it mean `E` being the highest scope, `F` is the direct child of `E`, and so on ....?

Comment: Yes that's right @HaPhan